# Grep not working for strings with ips

Tags: grep, ip-address

I am trying to print  all the following entries in my file as my output.Expected output is as follows (with differnt ip address)

```
all files calculateTotalcount 0 #211.4.2.10#expctd data flows
all files calculateTotalcount 0 #21.2.2.110#expctd data flows
all files calculateTotalcount 0 #11.44.2.10#expctd data flows
all files calculateTotalcount 0 #1.54.8.10#expctd data flows
```

Since my string had a space and had ip address, I wrote the grep in following format

```
grep -o -E 'all files calculateTotalcount 0 #[0-9]*'#expctd data flows'  inputfile > output file
```

I guess this works only on numbers and not ip address. Any advice on what modification can be made?

Comment: You seem to have an uneven number of quotes on that command line. I'm surprised it does anything.

Answer (score 3):

`[0-9]*` matches 0 or more of the characters that sort between 0 and 9 (which includes at least 0123456789). You can add `.` in there as in `[0-9.]*` to add `.` to the list of characters that bracket expression matches.

```
grep -Eo 'all files calculateTotalcount 0 #[0-9.]*#expctd data flows'
```

Or you could be more specific if you want to match only quad-decimal representations of IPv4 addresses:

```
grep -Eo 'all files calculateTotalcount 0 #([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+#expctd data flows'
```

Or you could be less specific with `[^#]*` for any number (including 0) of characters other than `#` (and newline since `grep` matches on one lne at a time) allowing other representations of IPv4 addresses or IPv6 addresses or host names...